# What is the reason why DNS works incorrectly on macOS?

Tags: dns, macos

How does DNS work on macOS?

I have a Mac and Cisco AnyConnect is installed on it. I connect to a working VPN. There is a DNS record for `grafana-exmaple.ru`.

When I come from Safari, it gives me everything. When I do `curl` everything works too. But when I try to `dig` or `nslookup` it goes to `192.168.1.1` and it can't find such an entry.

I can see that in `/etc/resolv.conf` I have `nameserver 192.168.1.1`, but how then will Safari and `curl` know the correct DNS?

When I do `scutil --dns`, I have one resolver with the correct IP DNS of the company server. I just don’t understand why `curl` works, but `nslookup` and `dig` don’t.

I am trying to change `/etc/resolv.conf`. It works, but I don't understand why `curl` doesn't need this change.

Comment: From my understanding curl act as a browser and Safari is one, so they rely on dns entries provided by the VPN, what dig and nslookup don't has they are relying on local config.

Comment: `dig` looks at the nameservers in `/etc/resolv.conf`.  If you want to use a different DNS server, try `host {dns} server`

Answer (score 0):

Tools like `dig`, `nslookup` and `host` query `/etc/resolv.conf` unless otherwise specified.

According to the [man page for `dig`](https://ss64.com/osx/dig.html) it specifically states:

> Unless it is told to query a specific name server, dig will try each of the servers listed in /etc/resolv.conf

Instead of `dig`, try using `host`:

```
% host domain-to-lookup dns-server-ip
```

Comment: Or tell`dig` where to look: `dig @dns-server-ip domain-to-lookup`